# PhotoSwipe conflicting with Wordpress media files

Tags: javascript, wordpress, photoswipe

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with an issue i'm having with the [PhotoSwipe](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe) slider on my Wordpress website.

I've downloaded and added the necessary files from PhotoSwipe and have followed the instructions to set this up in my markup.

The plugin works great however, because i'm using images from the Wordpress media file, when clicking on a thumbnail to open the Lightbox, instead of opening the Lightbox it opens the image in a new tab. I've raised the issue with the author of the plugin but i'm not getting a response.

It seems to work fine if the image isn't hosted on Wordpress.

I'm using the sample code from the website and the markup as follows:

```
    var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

        // parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements 
        // (children of gallerySelector)
        var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
            var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
                numNodes = thumbElements.length,
                items = [],
                figureEl,
                linkEl,
                size,
                item;

            for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {

                figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

                // include only element nodes 
                if(figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
                    continue;
                }

                linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

                size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

                // create slide object
                item = {
                    src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
                    w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                    h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
                };



                if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
                    // <figcaption> content
                    item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML; 
                }

                if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
                    // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
                    item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
                } 

                item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
                items.push(item);
            }

            return items;
        };

        // find nearest parent element
        var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
            return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
        };

        // triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
        var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

            var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

            // find root element of slide
            var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
                return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
            });

            if(!clickedListItem) {
                return;
            }

            // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
            // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute
            var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
                childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
                numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
                nodeIndex = 0,
                index;

            for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
                if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
                    continue; 
                }

                if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                    index = nodeIndex;
                    break;
                }
                nodeIndex++;
            }



            if(index >= 0) {
                // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
                openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
            }
            return false;
        };

        // parse picture index and gallery index from URL (#&pid=1&gid=2)
        var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
            var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
            params = {};

            if(hash.length < 5) {
                return params;
            }

            var vars = hash.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                if(!vars[i]) {
                    continue;
                }
                var pair = vars[i].split('=');  
                if(pair.length < 2) {
                    continue;
                }           
                params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            }

            if(params.gid) {
                params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
            }

            return params;
        };

        var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {

            var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
                gallery,
                options,
                items;

            items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

            // define options (if needed)
            options = {

                history: false,

                // define gallery index (for URL)
                galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

                getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                    // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of documentation for more info
                    var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0], // find thumbnail
                        pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                        rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

                    return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
                }

            };

            // PhotoSwipe opened from URL
            if(fromURL) {
                if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                    // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
                    // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                        if(items[j].pid == index) {
                            options.index = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // in URL indexes start from 1
                    options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
                }
            } else {
                options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
            }

            // exit if index not found
            if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
                return;
            }

            if(disableAnimation) {
                options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
            }

            // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
            gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
            gallery.init();
        };

        // loop through all gallery elements and bind events
        var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );

        for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
            galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
            galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
        }

        // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
        var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
        if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
            openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid ,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
        }
    };

    // execute above function
    initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.gallery');

<div class="gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
                        <?php foreach ( $projectImgLgBtm as $ImgFtLargeBtm ) {
                        echo 
                            '<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
                                <a href="'.$ImgFtLargeBtm['full_url'].'" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="'.$ImgFtLargeBtm['width'].'x'.$ImgFtLargeBtm['height'].'">
                                    <img class="scene_element scene_element--fadeinup" src="'.$ImgFtLargeBtm['url'].'" srcset="'.esc_attr($ImgFtLargeBtm['srcset']).'" 

                                    sizes="(max-width:40em) 767px, (min-width: 40.063em) 955px, 100vw" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" >
                                </a>
                                <figcaption itemprop="caption description">

                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>';
                    } ?>
            </div>  

    <div class="gallery">
                           <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <a href="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/1010x1514.png" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024">
              <img class="scene_element scene_element--fadeinright" src="http://via.placeholder.com/555x372" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
          </a>
                                              <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption  1</figcaption>

        </figure>
                            </div>
```

Is there anyway i can stop the Wordpress image opening in a new tab?

Many thanks,
Shaun

Comment: Check developer tools, open console and see if there are any errors. Maybe try fancyBox3, it is so much easier to setup

Comment: Hi Janis, thanks for that. Ive checked the console but not errors. Like i said, it works fine it's just Wordpress is overwriting it as each media file is stored as a post. I think i need to add preventDefault(); somewhere but struggling. I did check out fancyBox3 and it does look good. Reason for using Photoswipe is you don't need a licence to use it.

Comment: If your code executes correctly, then it adds `onThumbnailsClick` click handler and this handler returns `false` to prevent default action. So, if you really have correct links, there is no js error, then there is no much choose - try debugging that code or look for alternative :)